# Form fields in stateless component not being initialized using redux-forms and react-native

Tags: react-native, redux-form, stateless

I have a basic form with two fields that I would like to initialize with certain values. Even though I am passing the initialValues to reduxForm, the fields in the form do not show initially the values provided there.

Googling around a bit, it is still not clear to me whether this is a bug in redux-form or not.

Here is my component's code:

```react
const renderInput = ({ input: { onChange, ...restInput}}) => {
  return <TextInput onChangeText={onChange} {...restInput} />
}

const RegisterLocationForm = ({handleSubmit}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Location Key:</Text>
      <Field name="location_key" component={renderInput} />
      <Text>Location Secret</Text>
      <Field name="location_secret" component={renderInput} />
      <Button
        onPress={handleSubmit}
        title="Register Location"
        color="#70c000"
      />
    </View>
  )
}

RegisterLocationForm.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

RegisterLocationForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'registerLocation',
  initialValues: { location_key: 'A key' , location_secret: 'A secret' }
})(RegisterLocationForm)

export default RegisterLocationForm
```

[In this post](https://www.davidmeents.com/blog/create-redux-form-validation-initialized-values/) they propose to use the component lifecycle to initialize them, but I am using a stateless component, so I cannot use callbacks like componentDidMount.

Has anyone faced a similar issue? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I found out it actually works. However, I was doing TDD and the tests are the ones that are failing. Here is the test that fails:

```react
const middlewares = []
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)

test('renders correctly', () => {
  tree = renderer.create(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RegisterLocationForm onSubmit={ () => {} } initialValues={{ 
        location_key: '12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012',
        location_secret: '12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012'
        }} />
    </Provider>
  ).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

I set the expected value in the snapshot manually. The test is failing because the value of the field is still empty.

[image]

Shouldn't it be updated with the initial value?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I create JEST snapshot tests for my redux-form (in react) in this way. This format is working for most of my redux-form.

For stateless components, remove initialStateValues and replace store with: 
const store = createStore(() => ({}))

```react
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import RegisterLocationForm from '../RegisterLocationForm/RegisterLocationForm' //Import your redux 
 form component
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

jest.mock('react-dom')
const spy = jest.fn()

const initialStateValues = {
//Pass your initialStateValues of your redux-form component
}

const store = createStore((state) => state, initialStateValues)

const Decorated = reduxForm({
  form: 'testForm', onSubmit: { spy }
})(RegisterLocationForm)

const defaultFormValues = {
//You can pass form initialValues here
}

it('RegisterLocationForm renders correctly', () => {

  const tree = renderer.create(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Decorated
        {...defaultFormValues}
      />
    </Provider>
  ).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```